# I am trying to create a program to search and replace words in a text file using c

Tags: c

I had typed following code to implement search function only. My idea was to create a copy of the FILE variable 'fp' in the function search, in the name 'temp_fp'. My problem is that, when I increment temp_fp, fp is also getting incremented. I have been spending hours to find the error. Isn't it possible to create a copy of a FILE structure? please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *source;
    char key[100];
    source = fopen("search.txt", "r);
    if (source == NULL)
    {
        printf("null");
        return 0;
    }
//read keyword
    scanf("%s", key);
    fsearch(source, key);
    fclose(source);
}

int fsearch(FILE  fp, char *key)
{
    char ch, *temp;
    FILE *temp_fp;
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        temp = key;
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        temp_fp = fp;
        while ((ch == *temp))
        {
                        printf("ch=%c\tkey=%c\n", ch, *temp);
            ch = fgetc(temp_fp);
            temp++;
            if (*temp == '\0')
                return fp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a quick fix for your code is to call fgetpos to mark the current position and call fseek to jump back to the mark. just google fgetpos and fseek.

Comment: This code won't compile. `fopen("search.txt", "r);` seems to be.. .missing something.

Comment: @Peter Li, I was thinking to create the program without using using many standard function, anyway I will try it out, Thanks.

Comment: @WhozCraig, search.txt file should exist in your computer at the execution path of the compiled program.

Comment: Seeking specific strings is not so easy. When you find the first character matching the start of the string and iterate in the second `while` to check if it is the actuall string, if it is not you have to reverse back. It is way easier if you read the whole file to an array of chars. You can move where ever you want with just indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a pointer temp_fp, and then setting that pointer to fp. This isn't actually copying fp, but instead pointing to the same spot in memory as the original.

This link may be useful for you: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/

Comment: I have read everything in that URL, but still I couldn't find the solution to the problem. Is there anyway to copy a pointer variable to another? Now I feel that what I learnt about pointers is all wrong..

Comment: If you want to copy the data itself and not a pointer reference then don't make it a pointer. Just use `FILE temp_fp;` I haven't checked whether or not this is what you want. Just seems like an obvious error. You might actually want to use the pointer reference `&fp`.